# SAILS.JS : Asked about using js, css in each page sails.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sails.js

I have many files css, js different for each different page. but if I put the entire asset in the sail.js forder will get the layout.
I do not want that, I want to be able to manage the files css, js will be used in any particular page.
If css, js is then put into layout.js general, separately, also included in its page

Please support me on this issue